# global variable in Python, is this normal behaviour?

Tags: python

I have been using WinPython for coding a program that uses a global variable, this is the code:

```
def main():
    global listC
    listC=[1,2,3,4,5]

def doSomething():
    if listC!=[]:
        pass
```

The problem that I have is that the line that says if listC!=... throws me a warning that says "undefined name listC"; this program actually compiles and executes normally, but I would like to know why that warning appears if I have declared list as a global variable.

I would like to execute it in the following way:

```
programName.main()       //init the list
programName.doSomething()    //do an operation with the list
programName.doSomething()     //same as before
...
```

Thanks

Comment: I've gotta agree with jsbueno below, something else must be happening to listC in doSomething().  The code you posted works fine.

Answer (score 1):

With the parts of the code you are showing us, it *should* work - 
however, since you are getting the error, what is going on is that you are making an assignment to `listC` at some point in the body of the  `doSomething` function.

If there is any such assignment, Python will regard the `listC`variable as local
to `doSomething` - unless you put list it as global at the beggining of the function - and, of course, you also have to declare it as global in the function you initialize it - `main` in this case, and be sure that the initalization code runs prior to calling doSomething.

```
def main():
    global listC
    listC=[1,2,3,4,5]

def doSomething():
    global listC
    if listC != []:
        print "success!"
    # the following statement would trigger a NameError above, if not for the "global":
    listC = [2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be working...  It works for me.

```
def doSomething():
   if listC != []:
       print "success!"

def main():
    global listC
    listC = [1,2,3,4,5]
    doSomething()

>>> main()
success!
```

Comment: wrong as well. There is no such need - as long as it is declared as global in `main` and that code runs first.

Comment: @jsbueno Of course!  Don't know what I was thinking...  That works perfectly... changed my answer...